# React/Firebase. How can I save my updated data in my project?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I am trying to change the data - the changes are getting to my Firestore Database, it's ok, but when I reload the page or logging out and trying to log in again - the user data does not appear in my project, but is also stored in my `Firestore Database`. How to save and display user data in the project even after I reload the page?

This is my code

```
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [phone, setPhone] = useState('')
    const [language, setLanguage] = useState('')
    const [valute, setValute] = useState('')
    const [instagram, setInstagram] = useState('')
   

    const {user} = UserAuth()


    const createUser = (email, password) => {
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
            const user = userCredential.user;
            const uid = user.uid;
            setDoc(doc(db, 'users', uid), {
                email: email,
                name: name,
                password: password,
                phone: phone,
                language: language,
                instagram: instagram,
                valute: valute,
            });
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            const errorCode = error.code;
            const errorMessage = error.message;
            // ..
          });
    }

    const updatePerson = async(email, phone, language, valute, instagram, name, ) => {
      await updateDoc(doc(db, 'users', user.uid), {email, phone, language, valute, instagram, name})
    }

    <input type="text" placeholder={name || user.displayName || user.email || user.phoneNumber} className='form-control' onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}/>
    <input type="text" placeholder={instagram} className='form-control' onChange={(e) => setInstagram(e.target.value)}/>
    <input type="text" placeholder={email} className='form-control' onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
    <input type="text" placeholder={phone} className='form-control' onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)}/>
    <input type="text" placeholder={language} className='form-control' onChange={(e) => setLanguage(e.target.value)}/>
    <input type="text" placeholder={valute} className='form-control' onChange={(e) => setValute(e.target.value)}/>
```

Comment: Can i ask about what is `{user}` and how is it populated in UserAuth()? Well if it is the user from firebase auth - then the easiest way will be to create a custom Hook, like useUserData() which takes user?.id (or uid...), has a useEffech hook that attach snapshot listener to the Document and returns {email, phone, ....} and all the rest. But. Do not save passwords in database, that never ends in a good way.

Comment: @SergeySosunov Yes, it is `{user}` from `firebase`. And about passwords. I will definitely fix this! Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer on my question.

We are expecting that `onSnapshot` will magically be called right after our app loads - it needs some time to fetch document from our collection. I would add additional flag which indicate if data is still loading or not:

```
function useUserData(userId) {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(undefined);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!userId) return; // null or undefined is passed, so just do nothing

    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(doc(db, "users", userId), (doc) => {
      setIsLoading(false);
      if (doc.exists()) {
        setUserData(doc.data()); // found and setting a user
      } else {
        setUserData(null); // null means user not found in users collection
      }
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [userId]);

  return { userData, isLoading };
}
```

Then use it like that:

```
function Profile() {  /// or props here
 const { isLoading, userData } = useUserData(user.uid); /// if you use props just simple write uid
 if (isLoading) {
  return <span>Loading...</span>;
 }
 if (!userData) {
  return <span>Ooops. Profile not found</span>;
 }
 
 return <span>{userData.firstName}</span>
}
```

Comment: Well to be honest when i write answers - i usually test them, like i created a react app with firebase and etc, i had no issues as you had in comments. Now notes about this code: 1) if by any chance user is not defined `useUserData(user.uid)` will throw an exception. use (user?.uid) if not sure. 2) isLoading state variable is redunand, you can use if (userData === undefined) return loading, if (userData === null) return ProfileNotFound.

Comment: @SergeySosunov Clear! I'll take note. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Im using custom hooks for that purpose. That is pretty reusable and i can load multiple (specific) users (or anything else) in same time.

useUserData.jsx

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { doc, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../firebase";


export function useUserData(userId) {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(undefined); // undefined means not loaded

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!userId) {
      // null or undefined is passed
      setUserData(undefined);
      return; 
    }
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(doc(db, "users", userId), (doc) => {
      if (doc.exists()) {
        setUserData(doc.data()); // found and setting a user
      } else {
        setUserData(null); // null means user not found in users collection
      }
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [userId]);

  return userData;
}
```

Usage and additional explanations and examples

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react"
import useAuthContext from "../../Context/AuthContext";
import { useUserData } from "../../Hooks/useUserData";

export function Home(props) {
  const {user, updateData} = useAuthContext();

  // NOTE: Do not destructure in this way due to it will cause an exception for null and undefined values
  // const {firstName, lastName} = useUserData(user?.uid); 

  const userData = useUserData(user?.uid); // user might be undefined, so ? is used. Null will be passed but hook will work

  // I prefer storing form data in this way, look at handleChanges function
  // Important: this approach relies on input "name" attribute, it should match
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: ""
  });

  // Just to update the existing doc.
  const updatePersonSubmit = useCallback(async (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    await updateData(formData.firstName, formData.lastName);
  }, [updateData, formData]);

  // In setter you can get previous (current) value
  // this function that is passed as a parameter should return new object to set
  // new object consists of all ...prev fields it had
  // and one field is overriden by key (name) and will have a new value here
  const handleChange = useCallback((evt) => {
    setFormData(prev => ({...prev, [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value}));
  }, []);

  // listen to the userData updates and update the inputs
  // || prev.XXX is used due to data in userData can be null or undefined
  // inputs in React expects empty strings for bindings, nulls or undefined will
  // break everything, so using old value if any (initialized with "")
  useEffect(() => {
    setFormData(prev => ({
      ...prev,
      firstName: userData?.firstName || prev.firstName,
      lastName: userData?.lastName || prev.lastName
    }));
  }, [userData])

  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      {user && (
        <form>
          <p>Those fields are NOT in firestore, they needs to be set/updated with auth functions, not so easy here</p>
          <p>displayName: {user.displayName || "null"}</p>
          <p>email: {user.email || "null"}</p>
          <p>phoneNumber: {user.phoneNumber || "null"}</p>
        </form>
      )}
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <form onSubmit={updatePersonSubmit}>
        <p>Those fields are in firestore, they can be set/updated with firestore setDoc or updateDoc</p>

        <input name="firstName" type="text" placeholder={"firstName"} className='form-control'
               value={formData.firstName} onChange={handleChange}/>

        <input name="lastName" type="text" placeholder={"lastName"} className='form-control'
               value={formData.lastName} onChange={handleChange}/>

        <button type="submit">Save</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! I did everything according to what you wrote. Users are added to the database, but when I click on the `SAVE` button  in my `App.js` to change the data, appears  the error `userData is not a function` and the database does not change. What am I doing wrong? For your convenience I've created [codesandbox template](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-benz-bfbg8q). Please, maybe you can check it out? The commented out area is what I was doing before your solution

Comment: Because userData is not a function, it is an object that is returned from firestore, you called the Hook 2 times and it is just the "same" object returned, one is destructured in your case, another one is not. First - move this hook to a separate file, it has no place inside authContext. Next - im not seeing the exact save changes method you had previously `updatePerson` in your question's code, you should use this method.

Comment: Excuse me for troubling, but now I have an another error... `_hooks_useUserData__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_13__.useUserData)(...)' as it is undefined.`

Comment: @EugeneKliuchnikov You need to `export` or `export default` the hook function from the file that contains the declaration of it, and then in the place where you want to use it you need to `import` what you exported. Like `import {useUserData} from "../../Hooks/useUserData"` if just `export`, or import useUserData from "......"` if export default. The from "../..." means relative path from current file, i guess you know what is it and how it should be. I dont know about what you have so the paths i texted are just an example. `from "./somefile" in case it is in same directory.

Comment: Yeah, I know about it) But I don't know why this error keeps appearing. My `imports` and `exports` are correct. I checked it many times

Comment: @EugeneKliuchnikov try to restart react server, maybe something went wrong internally, i honestly have no other ideas without seeing the project and playing myself with it

Comment: I tried. It's useless. I am sorry I did not fully copy this error for you. It looks like this: `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'email' of '(0 , _hooks_useUserData__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_13__.useUserData)(...)' as it is undefined.` Maybe it means something to you?

Comment: @EugeneKliuchnikov something with the code, the destructuring, which is const {a,b,c} = someVariable or looks like the issue is with your hook, or your hook usage, i personally havent seen issues like that

Comment: @EugeneKliuchnikov Actually try using hook without destructuring, as per my example. If you try to destructure null or undefined (not an empty object) - you will get that error. Im getting a bit rusty already, so sorry, my mistake i guess

Comment: It's ok =) Thanks anyway for your help! I'll try to find the problem myself ))

Comment: I found the answer on my question. It helped me. Maybe, it can be useful for you in the future =)