# Why does the error appear when I use the useUserData hook?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I'm trying to use hook `useUserData` to save and display user data in the project even after I reload the page, but I have an error `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'email' of '(0 , _hooks_useUserData__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_13__.useUserData)(...)' as it is undefined`. I was advised to use the `useUserData` hook in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73198387/react-firebase-how-can-i-save-my-updated-data-in-my-project) but I get an error that we could not solve. All `imports` and `exports` are correct. What am I doing wrong? Maybe other solutions can be used here?

[This is my codesandbox template, where I use this hook](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-benz-bfbg8q)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are expecting that `onSnapshot` will magically be called right after you app loads - it needs some time to fetch document from your collection. I would add additional flag which indicate if data is still loading or not:

```js
function useUserData(userId) {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(undefined);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!userId) return; // null or undefined is passed, so just do nothing

    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(doc(db, "users", userId), (doc) => {
      setIsLoading(false);
      if (doc.exists()) {
        setUserData(doc.data()); // found and setting a user
      } else {
        setUserData(null); // null means user not found in users collection
      }
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [userId]);

  return { userData, isLoading };
}
```

Then use it like that:

```js
function Profile({ uid }) {
 const { isLoading, userData } = useUserData(uid);
 if (isLoading) {
  return <span>Loading...</span>;
 }
 if (!userData) {
  return <span>Ooops. Profile not found</span>;
 }
 
 return <span>{userData.firstName}</span>
}
```

In addition you are not actually saving anything after successful signup, it should be like that (the same with email+password):

```js
  const googleSignIn = async () => {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    const userCredential = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider)

    const user = userCredential.user;
    const uid = user.uid;
    await setDoc(doc(db, "users", uid), {
          ...data
        });
  };
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! I used your solution, but now it's constantly loading. And that's it...

Comment: @EugeneKliuchnikov in your CodeSandbox you are not waiting for data to be saved - `setDoc(doc(db, "users", uid)` - it is either missing `await` or `then()`

Comment: I don't quite understand you. In `AuthContext` in `createUser` function I have `then()` or what I should do?

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: Nope... It still keeps constantly loading. But the user is added to the database

Comment: I have updated my [codesandbox template](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-rgb-9gom6g) and brought in what I currently have in my development environment right now. Maybe I'm doing something wrong? Please, check it out

Comment: @EugeneKliuchnikov now you are not passing `uid` when you are calling your hook :D it should be const `{ isLoading, userData } = useUserData(...PUT UID HERE...)`;

Comment: Nope, it's not working. Sorry for bothering you =( It keeps constantly loading. I don't know what's wrong...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247011/discussion-between-piotr-and-eugene-kliuchnikov).